# PDF reader which has a Next/Previous button for viewing multiple files in sequence

Tags: windows, gui, pdf-viewer, plug-in, text

I want to switch between multiple pdf files just like I do with .jpg images in various viewers.
other features (not strictly required): fast loading; page cache-forward; good text rendering with anti-aliasing
OS: MS Windows
budget: does not matter

possible candidates: plugin for Total Commander (don;t know the name yet); PDF X-Change Viewer

Comment: PDF X-Change Viewer, I believe, is deprecated.  But PDF X-Change Editor is currently developed, and quite good.  It looks like, in mid 2021, someone requested this exact feature on their forums: https://forum.tracker-software.com/viewtopic.php?p=153582 - I don't think the developers have acted on that request, but hopefully they will choose to do so, as I also think it will make a quality addition to their product.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket they are also discussing a Preview pane in Explorer, but it is too generic - you cant zoom in, you cant make it remember the zoom and position for different files

Comment: Yes, that Explorer plugin really does not have sufficient functionality.  Plus, Explorer itself is really too limited... there are much better alternatives out there.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket i just had an idea that a fairly working solution, for when you really need to traverse between hundreds of pdf files - would be to stitch them together with a tool such as `PDFBox.jar`

Comment: Not a bad idea, but ewww.... I hope there is a better way! ;)

Answer (score 2):

[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/64bit.htm) with plugins installed reads .PDF and has exactly those buttons; loading is also very fast; you can zoom in and out with Ctrl+MWheel
can also keep zoom and scroll position (available from the View menu)

Comment: When your refer to "plugins" are you referring to the official plugins on the main IrfanView site, or 3rd-party plugins?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket the main website